# about read kinect depth information from matlab

Tags: matlab, kinect

I am using MATLAB 2015a
        I get the snapshot of kinect depth video from Kinect with format of .fig However,when I use data cursor to get the depth information, it shows different type of number, it indeed confuse me. 
[X Y]:[402 174]
index: 3201
[R G B]: [0.7843 0.7843 0.7843]
 what does index specifies? does INDEX specifies the physical distance of that data cursor point from kinect camera?
Thanx !

Answer (score 2):

Index is the distance to the camera plane in millimeters.

Note: If you want to do processing, you may want to try to get the depth data as an array, rather than as a .fig. If all you have is the .fig (and it's open and active), you can get the depth array as `depth = get(gcf,'CData')`